# How to prove the equality on the Fourier transformation of measure?

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, integration

I cannot prove the following equality on the Fourier transformation of measure:
let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure on $R^d,$ then 
$$\lim\limits_{T\to \infty}\frac{1}{(2T)^d}\int_{[-T,T]^d}|\widehat{\mu}(\xi)|^2d\xi=\sum_{x\in R^d}\mu(\{x\})^2,$$
where $\widehat{\mu}(\xi)=\int e^{-2\pi i\xi\cdot x}d\mu(x)$, i.e, the Fourier transformation of the measure $\mu.$

Anyone can help me? Many thanks!

Comment: Fubini and explicit integration of the exponential. Try with $d=1$ for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a classic theorem of Wiener ([1933, p. 146](https://books.google.com/books?id=L1U4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA146)).

Modern expositions see e.g. [Katznelson 1968](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=248482) ([Chap 6](http://math.stanford.edu/~katznel/23309/index23309.html), Thm 2.12), [Strichartz 1990](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1040961) (Thm 4.4), [Jaksic 2006](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2248985) ([§2.5](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/jaksic/Papers.html), Thm 6).

Comment: These youngsters.  They don't want to look in a book.

Comment: @Gerald Edgar : it always seemed to me that older people were less inclined to learn new things, and at least Bourbaki thought this as they put a 50 years age limit for membership. Dieudonné even states it explicitly that people are more attached to what they learned as youngsters, and that the uneasiness to accept how mathematics evolves and learn from it would eventually make one deviate from the original goal \text{e.g.} presenting not interesting mathematics, but necessary mathematics used to make interesting mathematics (this last definition is due to Jean-Pierre Serre).